# Can I cache SQL statements / ActiveRecord queries within a delayed job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delayed-job

In a rails application, the results of unique SQL statements within a single HTTP request are cached.  If the same statement is ran twice within a single request, the second query is cached.  This nicely results in the the following when User 18 is accessed twice during a single HTTP request:

```
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 18 LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 18 LIMIT 1
```

Can I do the same thing within a delayed job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can selectively turn caching on (or off) for blocks of code.  You can do this with a method used by Delayed job.

```
User.cache do 
  # caching is turned on in this block
  User.find(18)
  User.find(18)
end

User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 18]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 18]]
```

If you want to disable caching for a block:

```
User.uncached do
  # caching is off for this block
  User.find(18)
  User.find(18)
end

User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```